# Prism Module Referencing Portable Class Library

Tags: .net, wpf, prism, portable-class-library, modularity

So I have a WPF application that is using Prism Composition to handle modularity. One of my libraries that contains my Prism IModule, references a Portable Class Library. When I attempt to run my WPF application I get the following exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Composition.dll
>   Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This occurs inside the **InitializeModules** of my **UntiyBootstrapper** implementation. I am pretty sure this is because Prism is trying to load all the dependencies of the library containing my Prism IModule but I don't quite understand why it can't find that dependency. So far I have tried reinstalling the Windows 8.1 SDK because I read that is where that DLL should reside.

Has anybody else encountered this before or have any suggestions?

Update: I found that if I copy the System.Runtime.dll from this location: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5.1" and place it in the same location as my WPF exe then everything runs fine. I don't quite understand why the Prism library can't load this DLL then. Is it a limitation of Prism because I don't see the System.Runtime.dll in the GAC so how does is that dependency normally resolved?

Comment: Do you have ReSharper installed? This is a known issue with Resharper when you shelve or unshelve changes.

Comment: No, I don't. This error happens when I attempt to run my project that is dynamically loading Modules using the Prism library.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its Prism, if you create a wpf app, which then references a different library, and that library is depended on another one. Then your main wpf application needs reference to both of them.

Comment: The problem that I am having is related to Prism and the Portable Class Library combination because when you a compile a PCL for multiple targets it will reference any dlls that are different between those targets. In my case I see references to two System.Runtime dlls with a 4.0.0.0 version and 4.0.10.0 version. I believe this is causing issues with Prism because it is trying to load both and only one of those will exist on any given target. My curiosity at this point is if there is another workaround besides putting the dummy dll in the output directory.

Answer (score 0):

It appears from my research that there is no way around this limitation in the Prism Library other than copying the dummy DLL from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5.1". While this works for development, it would not be a practical option for deployment and therefore I have decided to just revert my PCL to a standard class library.

I came to my conclusion because after using a decompiler I saw that both System.Runtime.dlls for the targets I specified were set as references in my PCL and it appears the Prism library just attempts to load all the dependencies. This doesn't work for a PCL because one of the System.Runtime.dlls would be missing in every case.